# I can't install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS alongside windows 7 system restarts

Tags: restart

I can't install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS because system restarts as I choose to install alongside windows 7 and press continue till then everything goes fine. I tried many times but I didn't get success. Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: What if you choose **Something Else** and select the partition manually?

Comment: @g_p what if it wipe out everything ?

Comment: It won't. Select the partition in which you want to install, format it if needed and install in it.

Comment: I dont have any  partition which I can format but I have space in where I want to install it best case would be installing it alongside windows 7 and if i try it says `no root file system is defined please correct this from the partitioning menu`

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1-In windows 7 free up some space for Ubuntu. Keep at least 30 GB. Keep this space unallocated. Don't make it into a separate partition. You can create a separate partition using Disk Management utility of windows.

2-Now try installing but instead of choosing `Install alongside Windows 7` choose `Something Else`

3-In there you locate the unallocated space, select it, and press the `+` button.

4-In the drop down list you will find option `Swap Area` or something like that, choose it, and make the size near about the size of your RAM, and click OK.

5-If you have a GPT disk you will have to create `boot` area. Not sure create anyway. It does no harm. For creating boot area select the remaining unallocated space,click +, choose Ext4 and choose the mount point as /boot. Give 1 GB max to /boot.

6-Now create the main `root area`. Select the remaining unallocated space, select '+', Choose Ext4, take the max size available, aand choose mount point as `/`.

7-Click next or continue. It might show a warning message or something. Click OK.

HOPE THIS HELPS.

Comment: Well, why alongside wont work ? Why it just keep restarting whenever you choose Install Alongside windows 7