# No option to "Install Alongside Windows 8.1" in installer GRUB menu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

I have partitioned 15gb off of my Hard Drive to install Ubuntu 14.04.1 alongside my existing install of Windows 8.1. I have burnt Ubuntu 14.04.1 to a disk.

This is what I did:

[image: Windows Computer Management window]

[image: Install Ubuntu disk]

When I boot from the disk I do not get the interface shown in the tutorial. I get this:

[image: Install Ubuntu/Try Ubuntu/OEM Installatin/Check disk menu]
[image: GNU GRUB version 2.02...]

Am I doing something wrong? When I boot my computer I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to select boot device instead of it just booting into the disk like they do in the tutorial. If I don't I just boot into Windows.

Comment: Is this 10.04 or 14.04? 10.04 is no longer supported.

Comment: @NoTime - 10.04 is supported until April on servers, although I would not advise using it. The problem is almost certainly with uefi boot. You need to boot the bios and disable uefi to install Ubuntu, although I would advise against it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yeah it appears he mistyped it though with the images. I just wanted to be clear, since he wrote 10.04 twice. Jaycoub, that is just the GRUB bootloader, it loads the image of the LiveUSB/CD, what happens when you go to Try Ubuntu without Installing, or Install Ubuntu?

Comment: The screenshots show Ubuntu 14.04.1. Also the GRUB version is from 14.04. Text fixed.

Comment: @NoTime I tried just to use Install, and got a black screen for about ten minutes. The power button on my PC didn't work so I had to unplug it to get out of it. If this isn't the right version, then where do I get the right version? [This](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) is what I downloaded and burned to the disk.

Comment: @Jaycoub I see you are using Wubi. This may not be the best option. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice You may want to use a different method of burning a disk. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows A lot of people like YUMI because you can load multiple isos onto a stick.

Answer (score 0):

Select `Install Ubuntu`. It will take you to another screen, where you will get the option of installing alongside 8.1.

If you still have some problem try this

[I can't install Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS alongside windows 7 system restarts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/578309/i-cant-install-ubuntu-14-04-1-lts-alongside-windows-7-system-restarts/578315#578315)

Comment: I just tried this, It did nothing. I got a black screen, so I let it sit for about ten minutes. Nothing. I pressed all the keys on the keyboard, and it did nothing. The power button didn't even work. I had to unplug me PC.